# What's the best way to say: "which one is more true or more accurate"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, expression-choice

What's the best way to ask:

> Which one is more true, or more accurate?

... when talking about a choice of two words?

Comment: If you feel that "A" is more accurate and truer than "B" in whatever context you are working, you could simply say, "A is the better word."

Answer (score 2):

When you need to compare the effectiveness of two words A and B in expressing an idea,  you could say

- A is **more appropriate** than B
- A **fits** better than B

If you want to sound a bit more sophisticated, you could appeal to French and say

- A is the **mot juste.**

Answer (score 1):

Use *accurate* over *more true*. Trueness and falseness are absolutes, while accuracy is a measurable value.

Comment: Is this really what the OP meant to ask? Just asking.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Quasiperfect in choosing *more accurate* over *more true*.  I will add that when I find myself in a position to ask someone to pick one of two words, I will often say things like "which one is preferred?" or "which one is better style?" or simply "which one do you think is better?".

"More true" is always wrong, as truth is (supposed to be) an absolute.  Sometimes I'll ask "which one is more correct" even though correctness, like truth, is an absolute.  It would be better to ask "which one is correct?".  Like many things in English, there are a lot of different ways to ask the question, each with their own subtly nuanced difference.  If you provide more of an example I can give you more direction.

Comment: *"More true" is always wrong* is false, as it's perfectly reasonable to say (eg) "X is more true of Y than of Z", or "Now that you've fixed it, it rings more true", etc.